# About the basis for calculation of line height property using percentages inside of a fixed height

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm experimenting with using line-height to vertically align text inside of containing div. I find it strange that to do so using a percentage requires the use of (comparatively) astronomically large values. As you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ot0x6111/), I used 700% to push the text all the way down to the bottom margin of the containing div!

Any explanations? I'm curious to know what basis is used to calculate this percentage. Is there any danger that using something like this will break my page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

h1.enormous{
    line-height: 700%;
    font-size: 2em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div style="background-color:red; width: 300px; height: 125px;">
<h1 class="enormous">VOCÊ APRENDE</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`line-height` as a percentage (e.g., `700%`) or a constant (e.g., `7`) is calculated on the basis of the font-size.  Thus, the following declaration `font: 12px/2 Sans-Serif` will make text size 12 pixels in a line that is 24 pixels (2 * 12).

For your example, to place the text at the bottom of the container, using `line-height` property, you can do the following: http://jsfiddle.net/07r139tz/.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="enormous">VOCÊ APRENDE</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

h1.enormous {
    font: 2em/1 Sans-Serif;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.container {
    background-color:red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 125px;
    line-height: 125px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
h1.enormous{font-size: 2em; line-height: 20px; padding-top: 30%;}
.container{background-color:red; width: 300px; height: 125px;}
```

That should do it for ya.

Comment: ?? was there something wrong with the initial markup?

Comment: It's a solution not using line height. The biggest reason I can see not to use it is to save yourself in case you ever change your font size, or implement a color blind version of your website and mess with font sizes. It's also harder to read because anything with division is not easy mental math.

Comment: Yeah its bad practice to base your location of your font on the page using line heights. Line heights work best when text is wrapping and you are trying to space the text lines.

Comment: if you use em and a percentage to set up a location on your page, you are basically adding too percentages together, who knows what will happen but I sure don't recommend it.